# Understanding numpy's any function

Tags: python, numpy

I came across a function named [any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with `numpy` and I could not understand its usage in some context which is given as folllows:

```
if np.subtract(original.shape, duplicate.shape).any():
   # Do something
else:
   # Carry on with the usual tasks
```

Could someone help me understand what is happening here? What is being checked? The documentation says,

> Tests whether any array element along a given axis evaluates to True.

Is it being checked for equality? To understand this better, how could I rewrite the `any` call?

Comment: iterate over the array, check if any element is `True`.

Comment: @Shilo in the context of numpy ndarray objects, that isn't true, and the `<=0` is not true in python generally.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, you're totally right.. Only 0 is going to evaluate to False when checking an int. Updating comment.

If something evaluates to True that means that value is not None,False or == 0. the `any` function checks items in the array for the above

Comment: Is this the same as `if original.shape != duplicate.shape:`?  I can't think of a combination of shapes where the test would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.any(x)` checks if any of the elements in `x` is true. In your case, it checks if the arrays `original` and `duplicate` have at least a different dimension.

You could rewrite this as:

```
res = False
for so, sd in zip(original.shape, duplicate.shape):
    if so != sd:
        res = True

if res:
    # Do something
else:
   # Carry on with the usual tasks
```

Answer (score 1):

It's being checked for "True"ness.

Try this:

```
import numpy

print(numpy.any([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
print(numpy.any([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

The `any` method checks if at least on element in the given data is evaluated as `True`.

In python the [following things are evaluated `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

- `None`
- `False`
- any numeric zero
- empty strings, sets, lists, dictionaries ...
- anything that has a `__len__` method which returns 0 or a `__bool__` method that returns `False`

Everything else is evaluated `True`.

If the data checked by the `any` method contains at least one item that does not meet these requirements, it returns `True` else `False`